# Using hyphenator with GWT

Tags: java, javascript, gwt

Can anybody tell me how use [hyphenator](http://code.google.com/p/hyphenator/) (method `Hyphenator.run()`?) in GWT. When I simply insert JS-code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            Hyphenator.run();
</script
```

my text isn't visible :(

Thanks!

PS. there isn't tag hyphenator - can anybody add it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm new to hypenator, but I can suggest this workaround. Add this to your `EntryPoint` class and call this method in `onModuleLoad`

```
public static native void startHypenator() 
    /*-{
      $wnd.Hypenator.run();
    }-*/;
```

Comment: wow, onModuleLoad - thanks for it. It's that what i searched) I'll try it.

Comment: Thanks to Thomas, he added missing part.